# Proving order of certain elements in a group is the same

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have an exercise which involves groups. It's probably common, but I don't know how to solve it. It sounds like this:

> Let (G, $\cdot$) be a group and x, y $\in$ G. Show that ord(xy) = ord(yx).

where ord(x) is the order of x.
I just tried to write $xy\cdot xy \cdot \space ...\space\cdot xy = x \cdot (yx) \cdot (yx) \cdot\space ...\space \cdot (yx) \cdot y$, letting x and y outwards. I don't know if this is a good step and I don't know how to continue. I would be glad if someone could help me.

Comment: Note:  all you need do is remark that $xy$ and $yx$ are always conjugates, as $yx = x^{-1}\,xy\,x$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $xy\cdot xy \cdot \space ...\space\cdot xy = y^{-1} \cdot (yx) \cdot (yx) \cdot\space ...\space \cdot (yx) \cdot y$, so the elements $xy$ and $yx$ are *conjugate*. Prove that conjugate elements have the same order and use $(h^{-1}gh)^i=h^{-1}g^ih$.