# In group $G$, $xyx^{-1}$ and $y$ have the same order.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the result that in a group $G$, for any $x,y \in G$, the order of $xyx^{-1}$ is the same as the order of $y$. This is what I have.

> Suppose the order of $y$ is finite, call it $n$. So $n$ is the smallest positive integer so that $y^n = e$. If $n = 1$, $y^1 = e$, so $xyx^{-1} = xex^{-1} = xx^{-1} = e$. If $n \geq 2$, we have
> $$(xyx^{-1})^n = (xyx^{-1})(xyx^{-1}) \ldots (xyx^{-1}) = xy(x^{-1} x)y(x^{-1} x) \ldots (x^{-1} x)(yx^{-1}) = xy^n x^{-1} = xx^{-1} = e.$$
> Suppose instead $(xyx^{-1})$ has order $n$, so $n$ is the smallest positive integer so that $(xyx^{-1})^n = e$. If $n = 1 $, then $xyx^{-1} = e$. Multiplying by $x^{-1}$ on the left and $x$ on the right gives $y = x^{-1} x = e$, so $y$ has order $1$. If $n \geq 2$, we have:
> \begin{align*}
> (xyx^{-1})(xyx^{-1}) \ldots (xyx^{-1}) & = e \\
> xy(x^{-1} x)y(x^{-1} x)y(x^{-x} x) \ldots (yx^{-1}) & = e \\
> xy^n x^{-1} = e 
> \end{align*}
> Multiplying by $x^{-1}$ on the left and $x$ on the right gives $y^n = x^{-1} x = e$, so $y$ has order $n$.

The first thing I am having difficulty with is proving that this $n$ is the smallest $n$. The second thing is, I can't find a better and more rigorous way to do it than the $\ldots$ proof. I can't get induction to work.

> Suppose the order of $y$ is infinite. So $y^n \neq e$ for any natural number $n$. For contradiction, suppose $xyx^{-1}$ has finite order, so for some $m$,
> $$(xyx^{-1})^m = e.$$
> By the same algebra above, we get $y^m = e$, a contradiction to $y$ having infinite order.

> Suppose the order of $xyx^{-1}$ is infinite, so $(xyx^{-1})^n \neq e$ for all natural numbers $n$. If $y$ has finite order $m$, then by the first set of work, we get $(xyx^{-1})^m = e$, a contradiction to the order being infinite.

Comment: You don't have to "prove" it's the smallest $n$, you simply assert that as a case, just like how you have a separate case for infinite order. Also, induction is for proving an infinite number statements like a formula dependent on $n$. But $n$ here is a fixed constant, induction will never work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can prove that much more directly, just noticing that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, you have the equivalence
$$(xyx^{-1})^k=e \text{ }\Longleftrightarrow \text{ }y^k=e$$

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that "noticing" this is helpful, but proving this fact still requires work (and the relevant proofs in the OP are rather...scant, and don't use induction).

Comment: @user1729 Of course, this is not a proof, just a hint, and proving this fact is not straightforward. I just wanted to underline this fact, because once you have proved that, you have no more problem about "is it the smallest power".

Comment: You username is TheSilverDoe, but the animal in your profile photo has antlers?

Comment: @gen-ℤreadytoperish Well yes... Sometimes movie makers are not good zoologists.

Comment: It’s probably Harry’s patronus, not Snape’s then. I just watched that movie over the weekend and the doe in the forest had no antlers

Comment: Really ?? Oh my bad, then, I need to find another picture...

Comment: [Here](https://i.insider.com/5bf4262048eb1236e117b863) is the first time Snape’s patronus appears on screen, when it guides Harry to the sword of Gryffindor under the frozen lake. Also, that patronus is from the *Azkaban* film, when future Harry saves past Harry from dementors in the Forbidden Forest after using the timeturner.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  One fact about automorphisms is that they preserve the order of elements.  This applies in particular to any inner automorphism.  So perhaps just prove that $g\mapsto xgx^{-1}$ is an automorphism, for any $x\in G$.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma**. $(xyx^{-1})^n=xy^nx^{-1}$ for every $n\in \Bbb N$.

*Proof*. Induction on $n$. The claim holds for $n=1$; let it hold for $n$ (inductive hypothesis); then, for $n+1$ we get: $(xyx^{-1})^{n+1}=(xyx^{-1})^nxyx^{-1}\space\stackrel{(i.h.)}{=}\space xy^nx^{-1}xyx^{-1}=\space xy^neyx^{-1}=xy^nyx^{-1}=xy^{n+1}x^{-1}$. $\space\space\Box$

**Corollary 1**. $o(xyx^{-1})\mid o(y)$.

*Proof*. By the lemma, $(xyx^{-1})^{o(y)}=xy^{o(y)}x^{-1}=xex^{-1}=xx^{-1}=e$. $\space\space\Box$

**Corollary 2**. $o(y)\mid o(xyx^{-1})$.

*Proof*. By the lemma, $e=(xyx^{-1})^{o(xyx^{-1})}=xy^{o(xyx^{-1})}x^{-1}$, whence $y^{o(xyx^{-1})}=x^{-1}ex=x^{-1}x=e$. $\space\space\Box$

By the corollaries 1 and 2, $o(xyx^{-1})=o(y)$.