# Order of centralizer and cyclic group over $(G,\ast)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

I'm struggling to answer this question,

Let $(G,\ast)$ be a group with $n$ elements and $a\in G$ with the following property
$ab=ba \iff b\in \{ a^k\mid k\in \mathbb{Z} \}$,
if $m$ is the order of $a$ in $G$, show that at least $\frac{n}{m}$ elements of order $m$ exist in $G$.

To me, it initially looks like something related to the centralizer and cyclic group, maybe $Z(x)=\langle x \rangle$? Some research landed me into thinking I might have to use something like if $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ is cyclic $\implies G$ is abelian?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $ord(aba^{-1})=ord(b)$.

Comment: As @DietrichBurde said, $\circ(b) = \circ(a) = m$. From the given condition and the fact that $$\circ(a^k) = \frac{m}{(k,m)}$$ we must have $$m = \frac{m}{(k,m)} \implies (k,m) = 1$$ So, there are at least $\varphi(m)$ elements of order $m$ for now.

Comment: @VIVID Thanks for that, may I ask what does $(k,m)$ mean?

Comment: @homelessmathaddict that just means gcd

Answer (score 1):

The property in the claim means that $C_G(a)=\langle a\rangle$, where $C_G(a)$ is the centralizer of $a$ in $G$. Now, $C_G(a)=\operatorname{Stab}(a)$ with respect to the action by conjugation of $G$ on itself. Therefore (orbit-stabilizer theorem), all the $\frac{n}{m}$ elements of the orbit of $a$ are conjugate to $a$, and hence they have the same order of $a$ (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3829008/810157)), namely $m$.

Comment: Thanks, what is the exact definition for $Stab(a)$?

Comment: For an action $G\times X\to X$, $(g,x)\mapsto g\cdot x$, it is: $Stab(x):=\{g\in G\mid g\cdot x=x\}$. In the particular case of the action of $G$ on itself by congjugation, it is: $Stab(h):=\{g\in G\mid ghg^{-1}=h\}=\{g\in G\mid gh=hg\}=C_G(h)$.